# what is the operator to test if a cell is empty?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var the_cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('07 Weekly Data').getRange('J16');
  var cell_content = the_cell.getValues();
  Logger.log(typeof(cell_content));
```

When J16 is empty I get "object" in Logger.log()

So I cannot use e.g. `if cell_content == null`

How can I crate an if statement based on whether J16 is empty or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my webapp working on a google spreadsheet I just use:

```
 if (sheet.getRange(this.row, index).getValue() == "") {
     //Empty
 } else {
     //Has a value
 }
```

That works fine in all of my cases, If you have cells containing spaces though you might need to do a `trim()`.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
var the_cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('07  Weekly Data').getRange('J16');
var cell_content = the_cell.getValue();
if (cell_content) {
Logger.log('cell is not empty')
 //your code here
} else {
Logger.log('cell is empty')
 // code to execute is cell is empty
}
}
```

or: if you want to check for empty first:

```
if (!cell_content) {
Logger.log('cell is empty')
} else {
Logger.log('cell is not empty')
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem here would be if the cell contains a "falsey" value, like 0 or FALSE.